# How to read data and run a linear regression in Jupyter lab R kernel on DataProc GCP?

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I tried reading data from the GCS bucket on pyspark using the following code:

```
df_business = spark.read.json("gs://[bucket_name]/[filename].json")
```

I want to do the same using the R kernel on the Jupyter lab and run a regression model.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Did you refer [this](https://code.markedmondson.me/googleCloudStorageR/articles/googleCloudStorageR.html#auto-authentication) doc to read GCS using R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the following steps:

1. Configure googleCloudStorageR library with proper authentication with service account.

   `options(googleAuthR.scopes.selected="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform")`

   `library(googleCloudStorageR)`

   `gcs_auth(email="my-service-account@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com")`
2. provide project,bucket, object name you want to read

   `proj <- "project1"`

   `bucket_name  <- "load1"`

   `gfs_tmp_file <- "bqloading.csv"`

   `gogleCloudStorageR::gcs_global_bucket(bucket_name)`

   `gfs_file <- googleCloudStorageR::gcs_get_object(gfs_tmp_file)`

   `gfs_file`

Output:
[image]

3. If required, you can convert this raw data into R data frame following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71752333/reading-csv-file-in-r-from-google-storage-bucket-with-cloudml-or-googlecloudstor).